# How do I format and properly re-add a drive to a RAID-1 array?

Tags: linux, raid, raid1

I had a failed drive from a RAID-1 array (2 drives) replaced and now need to:

1. Format it.
2. Add it back to the array.

My drives are like this:

```
root@s01 [~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_server01-LogVol01
                      2.7T  416G  2.2T  17% /
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              477M  149M  303M  33% /boot
/dev/md2               32G  5.6G   25G  19% /mysql
/usr/tmpDSK           4.0G  220M  3.6G   6% /tmp
root@s01 [~]#
```

The /dev/md2 works fine. The /dev/md1 is the one that had failed. After the drive was replaced, it looks like this:

```
root@s01 [~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Sat Jul  7 18:23:24 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2929751932 (2794.03 GiB 3000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2929751932 (2794.03 GiB 3000.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Jul  5 10:54:30 2016
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : server01.domain.com:1
           UUID : 58600fc5:5348d92c:a7d25465:20d42940
         Events : 2281612

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       50        1      active sync   /dev/sdd2
root@s01 [~]#
```

I noticed it says "removed" and there's just 1 drive in the array. But there should be 2 identical ones in the machine, just one isn't formatted and added.

The drives that are in the array that works okay are:

```
   0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
   1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

So it looks like the one I need to format and add to the array is `/dev/sdc`? But how?

```
root@s01 [~]# lsblk -d -n -oNAME,RO | grep '0$' | awk {'print $1'}
loop0
sda
sdc
sdb
sdd
root@s01 [~]#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[First result on Google](https://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array):

`mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/<newdrivehere>`